# Adding new lines in two textareas after hitting a button and filling them with text

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, textarea, newline

I have a HTML page that has two textareas and a button.It is a custom SQL client, so user enters a command in the first textarea and hits the button.by using Javascript and AJAX the text will be sent to database and a result log will be returned which is shown in the 2nd textarea.

Like [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f9mzl4w06elfz0c/stack%20copy.mp4?dl=0) small video.

[This](http://pastebin.com/t7FeyHK6) is the whole code.

What I want to do is that after user writes command and hits the button;In the first textarea that commands are written, a new line should be added to it starting with SQL>
I can make a new line in the second textarea after clicking button but nothing happens to the first one. the code I'm using to do this is:

```
document.getElementById("in").innerHTML+=("\n"+"SQL>");
```

What am I doing wrong?
How Should I fix it?

p.s. I've read other questions about generally inserting new lines to textareas but they don't exactly solve my problem.

Comment: Replace `innerHTML` with `value`. The content in the textarea is a value, not innerHTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
document.getElementById("in").value+=("\n"+"SQL>");
```